# For loop run once or before function is complete?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I got a for loop and inside of it - each time it runs it should activate a function
but for some reason it (guessing from reading here) runs again before the function
is complete and thus i get only one variable instead of 8.

**Here is my current code:**

```
jQuery(function($){

    var elements    = 'linkCount, domainCount, ipCount, edugovCount, cclassCount, citationCount, trustCount, pagesCount';
    var elearr      = elements.split(",");

    for(var i=0;i<elearr.length;i++) {
        var currentElement = elearr[i]+'[]';
        // OK: COUNT = 8 -> console.log('i count: '+i); 
        // ERROR: RETURN ONE VAR -> console.log('currentElement: '+currentElement); 
        highlight_biggestval(currentElement)
    }

    function highlight_biggestval(currentElement) {
        // HIGHLIGHT BIGGEST INPUT FIELD
        var higesht_val     = 0;
        var higesht_val_id  = '';
        $("input[name='"+currentElement+"']").each(function() {

            var current_val = parseInt(this.value);

            if(higesht_val < this.value){
                higesht_val     = current_val;
                higesht_val_id  = 'input#'+this.id;
            }

        });
        $(higesht_val_id).addClass('bgYellow');
    }

})
```

Need some help figuring this out...

Comment: Are you sure your function call returns and execution doesnt stop in between, because in that case the control will never return to your calling function and javascript execution will stop. Add some alert statements to check.

Comment: `var currentElement = elearr[i]+'[]';` Why is that [] appended after the element name/id?

Comment: @abhitalks var currentElement = elearr[i]+'[]'; is there Because i am later using it to get a group of inputs... in the following function attached here...

Comment: @AakashGoyal i used console.log in the middle of for loop and commented it with the data each one returns... The function runs but only once. thats my problem actually ;)

Comment: You want to be calling `.split(', ')` (with the space) since I doubt your input names have a space at the start of them. The function runs more than once, it just doesn't match any elements after the first execution because the selector isn't correct.

Comment: @SagiveSEO can you put the console.log at the end of highlight_biggestval function and see if it shows up.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist oh my god! post it as an answer mate. (cant belive i spent 2 hours on that!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var elearr      = elements.split(",");
```

should instead be:

```
var elearr      = elements.split(", "); // note the space
```

otherwise your second to eighth elements have a leading space, resulting in incorrect selectors when passed as the argument of your function.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate... sometimes (many times!) its the small things.